# Eloquent no encuentra la clase

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, class

Tengo un problema. Estoy empezando con Laravel, usando eloquent y desde la ruta me lanza el error de que no encuentra mi clase.

Tengo la clase Paciente creada, desde la ruta intento llamarla usando el metodo "all()" pero me salta el error de que la clase Paciente la encuentra.

Esta es el Modelo de Paciente

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Paciente extends Model
{

}
```

Este es lo que tengo en el archivo web.

```
<?php
  
/* 
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

 Route::get('/', function () {
 return view('welcome');
 });

 Route::get("/leer", function(){

  $pacientes = Paciente::all();
 });
```

Comment: Paciente (*con P mayúscula*) no es lo mismo que paciente (*con p minúscula*), corrigiendo ese aspecto debe funcionar

Comment: Seguramente ademas de lo que dice @BetaM vas a tener que agregar "App/" previo al nombre de la clase, quedando de esta manera "$pacientes = \App\Paciente::all();", de esta manera detallas el namespace al cual pertenece la clase.

Comment: @BetaM, si, era un error que ya habia visto, olvide corregirlo al subirlo como preguna, pero gracias. El problema era el namespace, en el curso que estaba tomando, no lo ponian.

Comment: Considera entonces por favor editar tu pregunta añadiendo el código completo donde se observa la corrección que te hice además de que se note que no importaste el modelo correspondiente y puedes proceder a responder tu mismo tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que no estaba importando el Modelo

`use \App\Paciente;`

Tambien puedes simplemente especificar al momento de llamar a la clase.

`$pacientes = \App\Paciente::all();`

Pero es mejor siempre importar el modelo y ahorrarse el problema.